# Load git repo without composer.lock

Tags: git, automation, composer-php

I'm new composer user. I have Little question to experience users this tool. I have repo on git. It is possible automatic load the new commit without update composer.lock? 
Thanks for all asks.

Comment: Maybe, ignore.git file can you help  in this case. https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ look this documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add `composer.lock` to your .gitignore file, which should be in the root of your repository. If it's not there, create one with the command `touch .gitignore`.

Hope that helps!

ELABORATION: 
If your composer.lock file is already being watched by Git, you'll need to tell it to unwatch it before your .gitignore will become totally effective. Do that with `git rm --cached composer.lock`. This will remove the file from being watched by Git, but keep it in the directory.